# How can i create File from stream on flutter-web?

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, stream, flutter-web

I'm using minio-dart (https://github.com/xtyxtyx/minio-dart) for connecting my iDrive S3 Object Storage.

When getting files from Bucket with this code

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

String filePath = appDocDir.path + "/" + fileName;

final stream = await minio.getObject(bucket.name, fileName); //returns Stream<List<int>> 

File file = await stream.pipe(File(filePath).openWrite());
```

it works on iOS and Android perfectly.

But on the web release there is no filePath for creating File.

How can i create File from stream on flutter-web?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not trying to access any system file. I'm trying to download my s3 storage object (pdf) and display on the screen. But to achieve this i have to create file object from stream first.

Comment: void downloadFile(String url) {
   html.AnchorElement anchorElement =  new html.AnchorElement(href: url);
   anchorElement.download = url;
   anchorElement.click();
}

Comment: I don't try downloading url link. I'm downloading files over s3 object storage with api key. After that i need to convert streamed data to File object without path.